# can't remove a package

Tags: apt

here is my problem i can't remove the click package  :

```
aptitude -f remove click
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :                   
  click 
0 paquets mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 1 à enlever et 2 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de télécharger 0 o d'archives. Après dépaquetage, 88,1 ko seront libérés.
(Lecture de la base de données... 551823 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de click (0.4.43+16.04.20160203-0ubuntu2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 32, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Click', '0.4')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 102, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Click not available
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet click (--remove) :
 le sous-processus script pre-removal installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Job for click-system-hooks.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status click-system-hooks.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
click-system-hooks.service couldn't start.
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 click
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Impossible d'effectuer l'opération demandée sur le paquet. Essai de récupération :
```

Comment: Try `apt purge click`

Comment: i did but it's not working ... same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a bug in the click install/remove scripts (located in /var/lib/dpkg/info/click*)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/click/+bug/1486841

The issue is that click-system-hooks.service (systemd unit) needs to be running and report backs its status otherwise the install/remove script sees the status is not good and crashes out.  The work around is either to either modify the install/remove scripts to ignore the status or to manually get the service up and running before trying to install/upgrade/remove the package.

Althought unlikely for most user, make sure you have not installed a local python package also called click which causes a namespace clash.

When click is finally removed, do a final check in /etc/systemd (particularl under the directory /etc/systemd/user) and delete any hanging symbolic links to the click service.